# How do I pass label text by clicking on button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want that when I click on my first button the text of label is printed on the other label which is situated in the next view controller.

```
var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"] 
var buttonnames = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  frame = tableView.frame
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.width - 70, y: 0, width: 70, height: 40))
    button.setTitle("more", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle(buttonnames[section], for:  UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotonext(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    let  label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width:tableView.frame.width/2 , height: 40))
    label.text = self.categories[section]
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    return headerView
}

@ objc func gotonext(_ sender:UIButton){
    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
    return cell
}
```

my cell code is:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        return cell
    }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }
}
```

I want that when I click on the button the label text is shown in the next view controller. In my next view controller there is only one label. So the label text is always changed by clicking in any of the buttons. The label which is in the front of the button so when I click on that button only that label text is shown.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand the issue you are facing, could you please explain a little bit? Are you saying that when user clicks on button `two` you need to pass `Drama` text to next view controller ?

Comment: yes  and there is only one label in the next view controller

Comment: You **NETHER** can pass label to other VC **NOR** you can set label text in previous VC. You just need to pass a string from previous VC to next VC and in viewDidLoad of next VC you have to set that string into the label text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tableview viewForHeaderInSection .. use

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotonext(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button.tag = section
headerView.addSubview(button)
```

then in your function

```
@ objc func gotonext(_ sender:UIButton){
    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
    nextVC.myTitle = self.categories[sender.tag]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
}
```

In your NextViewController create a variable with name. You will get the value in myTitle

```
var myTitle:String?
```